# Remote Sqlserver Connected to windows application using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to create a windows application in C# and SQL Server, these have two databases one is in local another one in remote. I have 2 doubts:

1. Is possible to connect remote SQL Server in windows application?
2. Some time Internet may be not available (may be chance). This time I cannot fetch and store data in remote server, my application not running that time,how can avoid this situation?
   Full data available remote server, partial database only in local SQL Server
   please share ideas to me.

Answer (score 1):

> is possible to connect remote sql server in windows application?

Yes. Provided if remote connection in SQL Server is enabled. See [How to enable remote connections in SQL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)

> Some time Internet may be not available (may be chance).This time I
>   cannot fetch and store data in remote server , my application not
>   running that time,how can avoid this situation?

Check for connection to your server or `catch` exception to see if server is unavailable. Write the data on your local server or local XML file and then implement sync logic when ever your server becomes available

Comment: please give ideas about  sync logic , using xml